# Unable to call methods from custom RoleProvider

Tags: c#, .net, roleprovider

I've created a custom RoleProvider for C# .NET 4.0. I've implemented all of the required methods, and I have also added a few methods of my own. I've changed the Web.config to use my custom RoleProvider, but I cannot call any of my custom methods. For example, I've added the following method into my custom RoleProvider:

```
public void Myfunc(string user)
{
  var a = user;
}
```

However, when I attempt to call the method using this snip:

```
Roles.MyFunc("testuser");
```

I do not get intellisense for the Myfunc function and VS gives me the error "Unknown method Myfunc of System.Web.Security.RoleProvider. I can tell that my custom RoleProvider is being loaded, because I can set breakpoints in one of the required/overridden methods and it hits the custom RoleProvider. But how can I call my custom functions of the RoleProvider?

Answer (score 1):

`MyFunc` is not a member of `RoleProvider`.

Are you trying to create an Extension Method?
Then your method should look like this:

```
public static void Myfunc(this System.Web.Security.RoleProvider roleProvider, string user)
{
  var a = user;
}
```

If `Roles` is your own class and you've implemented `MyFunc` then you need to show us more code. But from the looks of it `Roles` is an instance of `RoleProvider` or if it is your class  itself then you need to make the `MyFunc` method static or create an instance of `Roles`.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem with the `MembershipProvider` and implemented extension methods to be able to call my functions via `Membership.Provider.MyExtensionMethod()`.  To do the same with a `RoleProvider` you would call the extensions like so `Roles.Provider.MyExtensionMethod()`

Comment: This works, but I think I oversimplified the problem...  I'm not sure what Roles is. But in the .NET framework docs, I saw this is how they made calls to the provider. The provider is instantiated by .NET from values in web.config, so I never explicitly instantiate it, it's done by the framework.

Comment: Roles is a static class in the framework. System.Web.Security.Roles.i am having this same issue. how do I extend the RoleProvider class and add my own custom methods?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your custom role provider is setup correctly. From there all you need to do is cast System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider to your custom class and call the custom method.

It would look something like this:

((MyProject.Helpers.CustomRoleProvider)System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider).MyFunc("testuser");